# Panel Grid Style Issue in migrating extjs 4.0 to 4.2.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

[image]My Application is migrated from `ExtJs4.0` to `Ext JS4.2.1.` In `4.0`, the grid is aligned properly where as in `ext 4.2`, the grid header and the content are not aligned properly(**Vertical lines are aligned zigzag and vertical scroll bar are cut off**).

**Updated:**
[Screenshot](http://img.techpowerup.org/130912/Gridpanel.png)
[image: ExtJS Grid]
<sub>(source: [techpowerup.org](http://img.techpowerup.org/130912/Gridpanel.png))</sub>

Comment: You're going to need to describe better or provide pictures.

Comment: I think that's the same screenshot twice

Comment: @Reimius can u see the vertical line alligned zigzag in the image , that is the problem am facing when migrating.

Comment: To clarify, you're talking about the header column alignments being off as compared to the data?

Comment: The examples on the sencha site do not have this issue.  It has to be something in your code.  Do you have custom CSS.  There is no way we can debug this issue without code.

Comment: sorry Reimius that was the issue with the custom CSS that we appilied.